# How to handle empty route parameters in express

Tags: javascript, api, express

Im trying to handle an empty route parameter if a path is not specified , I would like to return a new date if the route param is empty. So far server is responding like this: Cannot GET /api/timestamp/

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string", function(req,res){

let dateString=req.params.date_string
 if(!req.params.date_string){
    dateString=new Date()
    res.json({"unix": dateString.getTime(), "utc" : dateString.toUTCString()})
  }  

})
```

Currently the server is not responding with a json new date as expected, anyone knows how to catch an empty route param?

Answer (score 6):

Express uses path-to-regexp, so you can check out that documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#optional

You can put question mark at the end of parameters to make them optional parameters, like so .../timestamp/:date_string?

Comment: Where do you see it documented that a `?` at the end of a param makes it optional?  I can't find that in the [Express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) for parameters.

Comment: if you ctrl f for regex, its mentioned briefly, not really in the context of optional tough, They may assume we know this because we know regex. So you might have to combine our two answers.

Comment: so express using path-to-regex and they tell you some more about it https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp

Comment: It looks like the relevant doc is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#optional).

Comment: Express already uses `path-to-regexp`.  You don't need to specifically use it yourself.  I had upvoted your answer, but now you are suggesting the OP has to use an additional package and that is NOT correct.  This is built into Express already.  It is already an Express feature.

Comment: Ok I need more coffee before trying to explain stuff apparently. The comments to my original answer were asking for where the documentation was since it isn't thoroughly discussed in the express doc. I was just trying to point out where to find the info - with the path-to-regexp docs. I've edited the answer... again... Hopefully that's clear now.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you simply use:

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string?", function(req,res){

let dateString=req.params.date_string
 if(!req.params.date_string){
    dateString=new Date()
  }  
  res.json({"unix": dateString.getTime(), "utc" : dateString.toUTCString()})
})
```

You can simply check any variable or value exists or not,

```
if(variable){
   // this condition executed only when the variable has value.
}
```

if(variable) returns true when the giver variable is not

- Undefined
- null
- NaN

AND

it also has some value

Answer (score 1):

You do well in checking if your parameter exists. But you have your response only in that if block. I moved it out of the if block so that you will always send  a response. Noy only if `req.params.date_string` doesn't exist.

Edit: I added furthermore the question mark to indicate that your URL parameter is optional, as pointed out in the answer from justin.

```js
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string?", function(req,res){
let dateString=req.params.date_string
 if(!req.params.date_string){
    dateString=new Date()
  }  
  res.json({"unix": dateString.getTime(), "utc" : dateString.toUTCString()})
})
```